# Upgrade Spree from 1.1 to 2.1 did you have any problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I am thinking about upgrade spree to newest version.
Are there any problems about which I should know about earlier?

How many hours this can take me in simple e-commerce app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.1 to 2.0 upgrade path is quite complicated.  There are many major changes to the structure of the software including some invasive changes like:

- Namespacing of all models, and controllers
- Splitting the front end and back end out of core in to separate components
- Complete admin redesign
- Split shipments, stock locations
- Multi-currency pricing
- and much more

As you would expect, some of these changes are quite invasive.  The time to upgrade will largely depend on a few factors:

1. The number of spree extensions you use
2. The number of customizations you have made to the default Spree interface and checkout flow
3. The skill of the developer(s) doing the work

If you aren't using many extensions, and haven't customized the site at all, I'd still devote 1-2 days to make the switch.  The more customized your site is, the longer it will take.  If you use some obscure extensions, you may need to port them to 2.0.

If you have customized the look of your site through CSS, view overrides, Deface, or other techniques, you'll likely see a half broken user interface which will need to be corrected.

If you have customized controllers, you'll need to update them to the new namespaces and possible API changes under the covers.

All of these things will add to your total time to develop the site.

Note that 2.0.3 is the current release of Spree, and 2.1 is the current master version which is not recommended for production.

As Spree 1.1 is no longer supported for security fixes, I'd recommend starting the upgrade.  You should familiarize yourself with the release notes for each version (http://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes/) and be prepared for some additional unexpected changes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For us, going from Spree 1.3 to 2.0 was approximately 1 ½ months of work for about 1 full time and 1 part time developer.

Going from Spree 2.0 to 2.1 was *another* 2 months of work for about 2 devs. This is consistent with what I've heard other people's experiences are.

(The time estimates I have given here include dev, qa, and deployment time)